# problem with recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

Given that :

- $\ U_{0} =\frac{3}{4} $
- $\ U_{n+1} = \frac{U_{n}^2}{2U_{n}^2-2U_{n}+1}, n \in \mathbb{N}$

The question was to prove by recursion that :
$\  \frac{1}{2}\lt  U_{n} \lt 1$

I tried to solve this recursion, but at the end I found: $ \frac{1}{8} \lt  U_{n+1} \lt 2$

- $\  \frac{1}{2}\lt  U_{n} \lt 1$
- $\  \frac{1}{4}\lt  U_{n}^2 \lt 1$
- $\  \frac{1}{2}\lt  2U_{n}^2 \lt 2$
- $\  -\frac{1}{2}\lt  2U_{n}^2-2U_{n} \lt 0$
- $\  \frac{1}{2}\lt  2U_{n}^2-2U_{n} +1 \lt 1$
- $\  {1}\gt \frac{1}{2U_{n}^2-2U_{n}+1} \gt \frac{1}{2} $
- $\  {2}\gt \frac{U_{n}^2}{2U_{n}^2-2U_{n}+1} \gt \frac{1}{8} $
- $\  {2}\gt U_{n+1} \gt \frac{1}{8} $

**What am I doing wrong? or is this question wrong?**

Comment: Use induction. First show that $\frac {x^{2}} {2x^{2}-2x+1}$ is an incr1asing function on $(0,1)$.

Comment: You should show what you did, so if you made a mistake somewhere, it can be pointed out.

Comment: What you found is still correct as $(1/2,1)\subset(1/4,2)$ but it's not as tight as the problem wants. Hint: $2U_n^2-2U_n+1 = U_n^2+(U_n-1)^2$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2x^2-2x+1}.$ Then
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^2-2x+1}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-x)^2}
=\frac{1}{1+(1/x-1)^2}.
$$
On the interval $(\frac{1}{2},1),$ the function $(1/x-1)^2$ is decreasing, so $f(x)$ is increasing. Notice that $f(1/2)=1/2$ and $f(1)=1$. Therefore for $\frac{1}{2}<x<1$ we have $\frac{1}{2}<f(x)<1$. Base case: $\frac{1}{2}<U_0<1$. Induction step: if $\frac{1}{2}<U_n<1$ then $U_{n+1}=f(U_n)$ and so $\frac{1}{2}<U_{n+1}<1.$